# Code that work on Windows (it use nest_asyncio) don't work on Termux

Tags: python, discord.py, telethon, termux

So i have working (on windows) python code:

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
import discord

import credentials

discord_client = None
loopHoleChannel = None
task_discord = None

telegram_client = None
task_telegram = None

class MyDiscordClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        global loopHoleChannel
        loopHoleChannel = self.get_channel(1015386432900182056)

def handle_discord():
    print('Start:Discord.')
    global discord_client
    discord_client = MyDiscordClient(intents=discord.Intents.default())
    discord_client.run(credentials.TOKEN)
    print('Complete:Discord.')

async def async_main():
    global task_discord
    task_discord = asyncio.create_task(handle_discord())
    await task_discord

def main():
    nest_asyncio.apply()
    asyncio.run(async_main())

main()
```

But when i try to run it on termux(without root) i get this:

```
    [Exception in callback <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7b3e23db40>()
handle: <Handle <TaskStepMethWrapper object at 0x7b3e23db40>()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeError: Cannot enter into task <ClientEventTask state=pending event=on_ready coro=<bound method MyDiscordClient.on_ready of <__main__.MyDiscordClient object at 0x7b3e1f24a0>>> while another task <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<async_main() running at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/RedsFiles/DiscordBots/TelegramToDiscordBot/main.py:33>> is being executed.]
```

Well it's almost obvious that problem is in [`nest_asyncio`] but without it it wont work.

Question:
Is i'm right about [`nest_asyncio`] and if i'm right how i can make it work without it?

Comment: Can u specify which part of your code produce this error?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. The "it looks like your post is mostly code" warning is there for a reason.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs It isn't change anything but you right, i made it.

Comment: @SorryformybadEnglish error happened in "asyncio/events.py", line 80" but "nest_asyncio" used in [discord_client.run(credentials.TOKEN)](and on Windows there no problems).

Comment: We can't see the line number here. Stackoverflow didnt display. Kindly please edit your questions and focus the code in neccessary parts only

Comment: @SorryformybadEnglish [asyncio/events.py line 80] it it isn't my code it's python library it has no relation to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accorsing to [this issue](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio/issues/22) it's a problem with tasks not veing patched on linux.

The simplest way to fix this would be to use discord.py's [`setup_hook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.setup_hook) function to run your coroutines alongside the discord bot:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    async def setup_hook(self):
        print("setting up some stuff...")
        #TODO: Put your other async code here!

    def on_ready(self):
        print("ready")


bot = MyBot(
    command_prefix="/",
    intents=discord.Intents.default()
)

bot.run("your-token")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, it's work... well on Windows, on Termux "async def setup_hook(self):" don't get called. code: pastebin.com/Sddf1YPK output: pastebin.com/bEkB2LF9 (but discord bot is perfectly working it can send and receive messages)

Comment: Full wipe of Termux helped to solve last issue. (Reinstalling of Python and Discord.py don't work)